# Sharding vs nested chains

Tags: scalability, sharding, plasma

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between nested chains (Plasma) and sharding.

As I understand it now, Plasma creates a nested chain, periodically transmitting root hash state of the nested chain to the main chain while the nested chain deals with it's own logic without spamming the mainnet.

Sharding seemingly does a similar thing and the difference between them is not clear to me. Could you compare them, stating differences?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40340/7887)

Comment: Yup, basically the same question